# Harmonic function in the unit disk

Tags: real-analysis

If u is harmonic on $U^+$ and equal to zero on {$ x_n $ = 0} where U is open unit ball in $R^n$, and $U^+$ is the upper part of it. Let v be its odd extension to all of U.

Suppose also that u is $C^2$ only in the interior of $U^+$, and continuous up to ${x_n = 0}$.

Prove that v is harmonic over U.

The hint says use Poisson formula.

I know how to do the problem in the case where u is $C^2$ up to {x_n = 0}.

I have set the system $\Delta (w)= 0$ in U, and w = v on $\partial U$. And I expressed w in terms of v using Poisson formula. I tried to see if I could prove that w vanishes when $x_n$ $=$ $0$. For that I would need the integrand to be odd, which I can't see.

Thank you very much.

Comment: express $v$ from the Poisson formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel#On_the_ball and prove that it coincides with $u$ on $U^+$ ?

Comment: Not sure why you need to assume $u$ is $C^2$ on $U^+$ since it is given to be harmonic on $U^+.$ Do you know the local mean value property characterization for harmonic functions?